# Notepad++ add new line above changing syntax with replace

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have a constant syntax of "Se " but there is a number in front of it that changes. I want to add a newline \n before the number. I've tried using \c to address any character (for the changing number) during replace, I don't know how to get the number part to copy over or work.

this is what it currently looks like

```
1            hinge 2pk
1            Se wall cabinet                                                   
4            door 15x40"
```

I want the new line to be above any item that includes "Se", so that it looks like this

```
1            hinge 2pk

1            Se wall cabinet                                                   
4            door 15x40"
```

this is what i've tried so far (not including parenthesis)

```
REPLACE TOOL

Find what: [\C            Se ]
Replace with: [\n\C            Se ]

✓ = Regular expression
```

but this is what I get

```
1            hinge 2pk

C            Se wall cabinet                                                   
4            door 15x40
```

How do I get the number to the left of "Se" to copy down (as this number is always changing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
^\d+\h+Se\b
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `\h+` Match 1+ spaces
- `Se\b` Match Se followed by a word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gftIyt/1)

In the replacement use a newline and the full match `\n$0`

**Find what:**

```
^\d+\h+Se\b
```

**Replace with**

```
\n$0
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well,  try this simple code,  hope it will help...

Find:`^(\d.*? Se .*\n)`
Replace with:`\n$1`   or  `\n\1`

Comment: Thankyou! These all worked :D

Comment: You are welcome , glad it helped, I personally upvoted the fourth bird Answer,  it was amazing,